# Oracle APEX - setting field order validation

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two placeholder static regions on the page with 4 fields on each region with sequence of fields set to 10,20,30, and 40 on each region respectively.

When page is submitted, the first validation shown is on the second region and not on the first. I can't seem to figure out why validations on the first region do not get triggered first. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

While in Page Designer, validations are visible on "Rendering" tab, next to each item.

Now, navigate to **Processing** tab - you'll see validations there. Rearrange them to set firing sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure this has an impact on the final result. Is this potentially an issue regarding which items are associated in the validation?

Comment: Processes *do* fire in a sequence, don't they? Why would be different for *validations*? That was, at least, my impression, @Scott.

Comment: In sequence, yes, but also as a set. And why would this impact a validation being "shown in second region, not the first". Detail isn't clear.